# Stuck with Logical SQL Query optimizations in Relational Algebra (OR in WHERE)

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-algebra

I am stuck with optimizing  this SQL-Query in Relational Algebra:

```
SELECT * FROM R1, R2, R3, R4 
WHERE (R1.A = '1' OR (R2.B = '2' AND R3.C = R4.C)) AND R4.D = '4'
```

I translated it to the following Relational Algebra statement:

```
σ{R1.A='1'  ∨ (R2.B='2'  ∧  R3.C=R4.C) ∧ R4.D='4'}(R1 × R2 × R3 × R4)
```

My problem is, that I don't know really how to optimize the where statement.
I know that I can transform the last condition into `σ{R4.D='4'}(R4)` and move it down the tree directly to R4.
There exists some kind of rules for optimization, however I really don't know how to handle the OR. [Rules for Logical Query Optimization](http://www.cs.uni-paderborn.de/fileadmin/Informatik/AG-Boettcher/Lehre/WS_07_08/dbis1/dbis1k2-logical-query-optimization.pdf)

**But how do I optimize the rest of the where?**
I thought about using distributive rule to transform it into KNF,

```
(R1.A='1' ∨ R2.B='2')  ∧ (R1.A='1'  ∨  R3.C=R4.C)
```

which would allow me to handle both clauses independently. But I don't how to continue, especially in which order I should join or make the cartesian products.

Here is the operator-tree, I draw:
[image: OperatorTree]

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "optimize"? And what does this have to do with SQLite?

Comment: @CL Optimizing means, using the logical Rules of Relational Algebra to reduce the cost of the evaluation and to optimize the order of the query operators, e.g. move the select down as far as you can etc.
Tagged with sqlite, because the SQL-Syntax is for sqlite (I use sqlite as db system)

Examples: http://www.cs.uni-paderborn.de/fileadmin/Informatik/AG-Boettcher/Lehre/WS_07_08/dbis1/dbis1k2-logical-query-optimization.pdf

Comment: I might not be right, but in your translation you've ommited one pair of brackets.
In original query you have:
`(R1.A = '1' OR (R2.B = '2' AND R3.C = R4.C)) AND R4.D = '4'`
which should give you:
`(R1.A='1'  ∨ (R2.B='2'  ∧  R3.C=R4.C)) ∧ R4.D='4'`

Comment: Out here in the real world, I would distribute the `R4.D` check into the operands of the `OR` so that SQLite is able to apply the [OR optimization](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#or_opt), if it so chooses. This depends mostly on the existence of indexes, but such physical considerations are not part of your current task. Anyway, doing the `R4.D` check before the `R3`/`R4` join should improve selectivity.

Comment: @T_G Yes, you are right.

Comment: @CL Yes. I already considered this. If the selectivity condition consists of conjunctions (AND)  they can be splitted and their order can be changed.
When I use the distribution rule, I can split up the OR-Clause Term in two separate clauses, seperated with AND.
However I am not sure, in which order I should add the Relations R1 to R4, e.g. which selection I should do first.

Comment: "Selection" and "selectivity" are different things. Please read the page I linked to; the OR optimization can also be applied in relational algebra.

Comment: @CL I think I mixed up the terms here. If i understand it right, the OR-Optimization  (the 2nd rule on the page) does the same as which is stated in the Wiki article below. Splitting up the OR-Terms into a union.


[Wikipedia article on RA Query optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Use_of_algebraic_properties_for_query_optimization)

Comment: @CL I think I figured it out:
http://i.imgur.com/9M2VYwA.png

Comment: 1. The parentheses in your start tree are wrong differently from the translation in the text, compared to the SQL. (Please fix.) Re your comment with answer: a. R2 is missing. b. Please make that comment an answer that includes the linked figure. (Comments are ephemeral.) c. U operands must have the same column set. So in your link R1 would have to have the same columns as the other U operand. You haven't said that that is so, and if it isn't then the tree is invalid, and you may need to map the original ∨ to an ∨ in a selection/rest rather than U.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union was not possible because it would have needed the same kind of columns.
I now got an official solution from my tutor.
As I already thought about, it was needed to tranform it using the distributivity rule to transform it into KNF, so that I have two clauses separate clauses.

[image: Solution for the problem]

Answer (score 1):

A good way to deal with disjunctions during query optimization, is to convert the selection condition into disjunctive normal form (DNF), and then rewrite the selection into a Union of selections (one per disjunct).

I.e. apply rule #2 here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Breaking_up_selections_with_complex_conditions

As most tricks in query optimization it works well in some cases and not in others - that's why SQL optimizers search a space of plans, trying to come up with a decent one.

Comment: But the UNION operands must have the same column set. DNF doesn't guarantee that . (Ie its ORs don't map to UNION.) With this question there isn't enough info to satisfy that unless you UNION two joins of all relations, which isn't going to be an optimization. (See my comment on the question.)

Comment: With this rewrite rule, you have to UNION two joins of all relations (otherwise, you'd get a wrong result).

I.e. the original query will be:
SELECT * FROM R1, R2, R3, R4 
WHERE (R1.A = '1' AND R4.D = ‘4’) 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM R1, R2, R3, R4 
(R2.B = '2' AND R3.C = R4.C AND R4.D = '4')

In this case it is not an optimization (hence my disclaimer in the answer), but after the rewrite it is much easier to see that the query is asking for a series of Cartesian products, so not much can be done to optimize it.

Comment: Your comment just repeats my comment, so I don't know why you wrote your comment. Moreover if per my comment here you read my comment on the question then you will find that optimization of the start query is possible by mapping ∨ to an ∨ in a selection/restriction rather than U. LIke in the correct answer Christoph S just posted. (And not on the incorrect one he linked by comment earlier.)